# Variable is nii?

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm using LOVE2D and Lua for making games recently. I'm updating Breakout and I have an error in `Paddle.lua`.

Code:

```
Paddle = Class{}

--[[
    Our Paddle will initialize at the same spot every time, in the middle
    of the world horizontally, toward the bottom.
]]

size = math.random(4)

function Paddle:init(skin, size)
    -- x is placed in the middle
    self.x = VIRTUAL_WIDTH / 2 - 32

    -- y is placed a little above the bottom edge of the screen
    self.y = VIRTUAL_HEIGHT - 32

    -- start us off with no velocity
    self.dx = 0
    
    self.size = size
    
    self.height = 16
    if self.size == 1 then
        self.width = 32
    elseif self.size == 3 then
        self.width = 96
    elseif self.size == 4 then
        self.width = 128
    else
        self.width = 64
    end

    -- the skin only has the effect of changing our color, used to offset us
    -- into the gPaddleSkins table later
    self.skin = skin
end

function Paddle:update(dt)
    -- keyboard input
    if love.keyboard.isDown('left') then
        self.dx = -PADDLE_SPEED
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown('right') then
        self.dx = PADDLE_SPEED
    else
        self.dx = 0
    end

    -- math.max here ensures that we're the greater of 0 or the player's
    -- current calculated Y position when pressing up so that we don't
    -- go into the negatives; the movement calculation is simply our
    -- previously-defined paddle speed scaled by dt
    if self.dx < 0 then
        self.x = math.max(0, self.x + self.dx * dt)
    -- similar to before, this time we use math.min to ensure we don't
    -- go any farther than the bottom of the screen minus the paddle's
    -- height (or else it will go partially below, since position is
    -- based on its top left corner)
    else
        self.x = math.min(VIRTUAL_WIDTH - self.width, self.x + self.dx * dt)
    end
end

--[[
    Render the paddle by drawing the main texture, passing in the quad
    that corresponds to the proper skin and size.
]]
function Paddle:render()
    love.graphics.draw(gTextures['main'], gFrames['paddles'][self.size + 4 * (self.skin - 1)],
        self.x, self.y)
end
```

Error:

```
Error

src/Paddle.lua:83: attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'size' (a nil value)


Traceback

src/Paddle.lua:83: in function 'render'
src/states/ServeState.lua:68: in function 'render'
src/StateMachine.lua:26: in function 'render'
main.lua:210: in function 'draw'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

Saying that the value is nii even though I assigned it. How do I fix this?

Comment: Move size to inside `paddle:init` or put it in `love:load()` if you don't want it to be a variable for paddle. Or try to figure out another way to work with global variables in lua.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function parameters are local to the function's body. So inside `Paddle.Init` `size` is a local variable that shadows the global variable `size`.

As you call `Paddle.Init` without providing the `size` parameter, `size` is `nil` within the function leading to the observed error.

See [Wikipedia: Variable Shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

Many people use a prefix to denote global variables. `g_size` for example. Then you could do something like:

```
g_size = 4

function Paddle:Init(skin, size)
  self.size = size or g_size
end
```

Which would make `self.size` default to `g_size` if the `size` parameter is not provided.

Another option is to call the paddle constructor with your global size as input.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Piglet. I will try and if it works, I will check your answer.